# Unexpected Behaviour of if statement inside loop over d.items()

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

Using Python 3.3 I want to loop over  d.items() and return matches based on if condition. Here is the code:

```
d = {'mohammed': '123456789', 'john': '1230012'}
for k, v in d.items(): 
     if k == 'mohammed' and v == '123456789':
            print("Match")
     else: 
            print("No Match")
```

I expect to print "Match", however what I get is that both the statements print in reverse, i.e.,

```
No Match
Match
```

How to get the code print only the right statement? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dicts are unordered, so there's no telling what order they'll be iterated over. I suggest using an OrderedDict.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for suggestion. I tried using OrderedDict but the output is executing both statements

Comment: @ Syed Mauze Rehan, No order is not necessary. The size of the dictionary will be less than 100 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered, so the entries in `d` may not be stored in the same order you typed them. Therefore, the order in which `d.items()` iterates over the entries in `d` cannot be predicted exactly.

When you iterate over `d.items()`, you are iterating over all key,value pairs. Therefore, if a pair matches your if-condition, `Match` will be printed. By the same reasoning, if a pair does not match your if-condition, `No Match` will be printed.

In your case, the order of key,value pairs during the iteration over `d.items()` is exactly the opposite of the order in which you've entered them. Let's take a look at this:

The first key,value pair to be considered is `'john': '1230012'`. This does not match your if-condition. Therefore `No Match` is printed.

The next pair is `'mohammed': '123456789'`, which does match your if-condition. Therefore `Match` is printed.

You can confirm this by adding a `print(k,v)` before your if-statement

Now, if for some reason, you want features of dictionary, and you want to maintain the order in which you've entered your data, then I'd recommend using [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

In  your post, you say "I expect to print `Match`". I think therefore, what you're looking for, is a way to check if there are **any** key,value pairs in the dictionary that satisfy your if-condition. Here are two ways in which you can accomplish this:

```
d = {'mohammed': '123456789', 'john': '1230012'}

found = False
for k,v in d.items():
    if k == 'mohammed' and v == '123456789':
        print("Match")
        found = True

if not found:  # equivalently, if found == False:
    print("No Match")
```

This will print `Match` as many times as there are key,value pairs that do match your if-condition. If however, you want to print `Match` only once even if multiple pairs match your if-condition, then you make a small modification to the above code:

```
d = {'mohammed': '123456789', 'john': '1230012'}

found = False
for k,v in d.items():
    if k == 'mohammed' and v == '123456789':
        found = True

if found:
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```

Of course, there's a handy one-liner for all of this:

```
if any(k == 'mohammed' and v == '123456789' for k,v in d.items()):
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```

Comment: what you have said is totally correct. I did include print(k,v) and it printed the k,v at the end. So, can I assume dictionaries are not the right data structure for performing such tasks?

Comment: @Mohammed: check out the update. I think you'll find what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you, ispectorG4dget, for being of help to me. The code which prints match only once was what I was looking for. I have simplified the question here. The real business is that  I am designing a log-in screen interface for some application and I decided to store combinations of user_names and passwords in a dictionary because they are immutibale and easy for look up. By the way, I am just learning Python by myself. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mohammed: happy to be of help. Note: Dictionaries are not immutable - they are very mutable. Perhaps you want a `frozendict`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, dictionaries(Dict objects) are un ordered so you can't be sure which item is accessed/iterated first.

Secondly, by the looks of it(assuming) that you want just a *Match* or *No Match* for an output.

You can do this by simple having a boolean;

```
matched = False
for k, v in d.items(): 
    if k == 'mohammed' and v == '123456789':
       print("Match")
       matched = True
       break

if not matched:
   print("No Match")
```

OR

If you want to access these in order, you can change your data structure to something like

```
[('muhammad','somevalue'),(),...]
```

Then you may iterate on this list and have something like

```
for obj in d: 
    t_val_1, t_val_2 = obj
    if t_val_1 == 'mohammed' and t_val_2 == '123456789':
       print("Match")
    else:
       print("No Match")
```

Comment: the idea of changing the data structure from dict to list of tuples is great. I am working on it right now. Thanks for help.